# Has XOR EAX, EBX another purpose?

Tags: assembly

I have the following line in an assembler code:

```
 XOR EAX, EBX
```

So, then I've searched a little bit and found out that XOR represents a "swap algorithm". You can read it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

But when I look in register window of ollydbg, then I have the following

```
 EAX = 00000068
 EBX = 0000003B
```

Now, after the line the register window says

```
EAX = 000000053
EBX = 0000003B
```

But from that what I have read in wikipedia article I would expect the following

```
EAX = 0000003B
EBX = 00000053
```

At the end, i can say that a normal XOR operation is performed because:

```
0111011   =>EAX=0000003B 
1101000   =>EBX=00000068
-------
1010011   =>EAX=00000053
```

So my question would be why the swap algorithm is not performed. Or in other words: When can I expect the swap algorithm?

Comment: the instruction for swapping data is [`xchg`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_328.html), not `xor`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the first answer states, XOR is a bitewise XOR, not an XOR swap.

To do the Xor swap that you referenced from wikipedia it takes *3 instructions* :

```
xor eax, ebx
xor ebx, eax
xor eax, ebx
```

Since you asked about the *purpose* of XOR I thought I would include some other concepts for you to read up on, so you might have an idea of what to expect from XORs

You can use XOR to clear a register:

```
xor eax,eax
```

Calculate absolute value:

```
cdq
xor eax,edx
sub eax,edx
```

XORs can be used for Crypto:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

XORs are used in the CRC checksum algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

XORs can be used to calculate Gray codes:
http://www.morkalork.com/mork/article/74/How_to_understand_and_use_Gray_code.htm#.U6RhN_ldXvI

This is just the tip of the iceberg. The instruction can be used in a large number of situations.

Answer (score 11):

The `XOR` mnemonic does not represent an XOR swap; it represents a [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_XOR).